# Do I need to wait for my UDP socket to be connected before sending anything?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I have written a class which sends some messages to a UDP socket. I noticed that at the start on my first try using the socket, it would timeout. When I went to do a wireshark capture, I kept seeing the first packet not being sent from my machine which is causing a timeout as the server needs to have two messages before sending a status back. Here is my code.

```
DatagramSocket socketN = null;
try {
    socketN = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramPacket connect = new DatagramPacket(connectMsg, connectMsg.length, ipAddr, port);
    socketN.send(connect);
    socketN.setSoTimeout(5000);
    DatagramPacket start = new DatagramPacket(startMsg, startMsg.length, ipAddr, port);
    DatagramPacket status = new DatagramPacket(status, status.length);
    socketN.send(start);
    socketN.receive(status);
} catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    socketN.close();
}
```

Based on the code and my wireshark capture, I can see the message start being sent from my PC but not the message connect. This block of code is repeated a number of times so on other times it is repeated the timeout does not occur.

Comment: There is no such thing as a connect message in UDP, unless it is part of your application protocol. The answer to your question is therefore also part of your application protocol, and only you can answer it.

Comment: If you want to establish a fixed connection like that, then you should probably be using TCP instead of UDP. Because UDP is designed in such a way that packet loss can happen, and you cannot guarantee that you message will be received by the client or server. From the wikipedia page "**UDP provides no guarantees to the upper layer protocol for message delivery and the UDP layer retains no state of UDP messages once sent.**"